Convert cURL to Delphi
I am using Delphi 10.2.  I have generated this cURL statement using the tools supplied by the API provider and in that environment it runs successfully and returns a result.
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.netradyne.com/driveri/v1/tenants/N251887947004171/driver/assignment \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept-Language: en-US' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access token replaced>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "driverID": "48625329",
  "vehicleID": "1393",
  "action": "login",
  "startTimestamp": 1720439154012,
  "endTimestamp": 1720439208018
}'

I have successfully reproduced one other cURL statement using the REST Debugger, but the best I can get is a response that starts off with "400:Bad Request - 0 bytes of data returned...".
The REST Debugger file is:
{
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://api.netradyne.com/driveri/v1/tenants/N251887947004171/driver/assignment",
    "resource": "",
    "contenttype": "application/json",
    "auth": {
        "method": "OAUTH2",
        "username": "",
        "passwordkey": "",
        "password": "",
        "clientid": "",
        "clientsecret": "",
        "authcode": "",
        "accesstoken": "Bearer <access token replaced>",
        "accesstokensecret": "",
        "requesttoken": "",
        "requesttokensecret": "",
        "refreshtoken": "",
        "signaturemethod": "",
        "responsetype": "code",
        "endpointauth": "",
        "endpointaccesstoken": "",
        "endpointrequesttoken": "",
        "endpointredirect": "",
        "authscope": ""
    },
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "Bearer <access token replaced>",
            "kind": "HEADER",
            "encode": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "application/json",
            "kind": "HEADER",
            "encode": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json",
            "kind": "HEADER",
            "encode": false
        },
        {
            "name": "data",
            "value": "{\"driverID\": \"48625329\",\"vehicleID\": \"1393\",\"action\": \"login\",\"startTimestamp\": 1720439154012,\"endTimestamp\": 1720439208018}",
            "kind": "BODY",
            "encode": false
        }
    ],
    "body": ""
}

Any thoughts on how to get Delphi to produce what this API is looking for?

I'm not familiar with the REST Debugger, but the file looks off to me. The accesstoken field should contain only the token by itself, not include the Bearer prefix. That prefix should only be used with the Authorization header. Also, why is the JSON in the parameters array and not in the body field?

Nobody understands HTTP and JSON anymore these days. :( You don't even wonder about {"parameters": [{"kind": "BODY"}]} versus {"body": ""}? A HTTP POST request with an empty payload will surely result in a HTTP 400 response.

I removed the "Bearer" from the accesstoken field and moved the JSON from the parameters to the body.  The JSON that the REST Debugger produced included "body": "ZGF0YT17ImRyaXZlcklEIjogIjQ4NjI1MzI5IiwidmVoaWNsZUlEIjogIjEzOTMiLCJhY3Rpb24iOiAibG9naW4iLCJzdGFydFRpbWVzdGFtcCI6IDE3MjA0MzkxNTQwMTIsImVuZFRpbWVzdGFtcCI6IDE3MjA0MzkyMDgwMTh9".  Running the request in the debugger generated a Windows alert sound and "(no response)".
When I used the debugger to create Delphi components, I got a TRESTRequest where the last parameter in Params had the namebody, the kind pkREQUESTBODY and the value was blank.  I populated the Value of the body parameter with the value of the "data" from the cURL statement and plunked down a button to execute the TRESTRequest and display the Content property of the the TRESTResponse.  What I got was

{"data":{"message":"Driver integration data received successfully."}}

Which was the expected result from the cURL statement.  Yay.
Thanks for the help Remy
